# How to schedule Azure Machine learning experiment periodically and also give admin to run it when he wants

Tags: azure, scheduler, azure-logic-apps, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a published AzureML experiment and now I want to schedule that experiment periodically and also want to give flexibility to admin to run that experiment when he wants.

I tried running experiment periodically using Logic App azure service but getting an error "This session has timed out. To see the latest run status, navigate to the runs history blade.". Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Maybe look at Azure Data Factory for this. You can set up to run the experiment and have it run on a schedule or manually kick it off.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for replying. Is there any link or document which I can refer to do this?

Comment: Sure, check out this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-machine-learning). I will say, that I think this is the same activity as from the version 1 of Azure Data Factory so it won't be as easy to use as the others. Hopefully, the team will get it updated at some point.

Comment: Hi Jon, Is it possible to run deployed Rscript files in Azure VM using Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Actually, it's easy to run an R script through Azure Databricks. Can probably do it with an HDInsight VM, too. Databricks is easier to set up, I would say.

Comment: Is there any documentation which I can refer to?

Comment: [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook) should be what you need.